# Accessing value during runtime on nested control (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to access value from nested control. My intention was to neatly display textbox by dynamically creates a flowlayoutpanel (layoutUI) with the direction from left to right. On that "layoutUI",  it will then **added** into another flowlayoutpanel (flowPanel) with the direction from top to bottom.

On the btnUpdate, I was only able to grasp value within flowPanel but **not** layoutUI. The result should be the value within **layoutUI**

```
 List<String> label = new List<String>();
 List<String> type = new List<String>();
 public TextBox createUIlabel(string element, int index)
 {
     TextBox txtBoxUIlabel = new TextBox();
     txtBoxUIlabel.Name = "txtLabel" + (index+1).ToString();
     controlLabel.Add(txtBoxUIlabel.Name);
     txtBoxUIlabel.Text = element.ToString();

     return txtBoxUIlabel;
 }

 private void formProjectParameter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ...
     while (dbConnector.reader.Read())
     {
         label.Add(dbConnector.reader.GetString(1));
         type.Add(dbConnector.reader.GetString(2));
     }
 }

for (int i = 0; i < label.Count; i++)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel layoutUI = new FlowLayoutPanel();                        
    layoutUI.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
    layoutUI.Size = new Size(450, 30);

    layoutUI.Controls.Add(createUIlabel(label[i].ToString(),i));
    flowPanel.Controls.Add(layoutUI);
}           
}
            }
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox txt = (TextBox)this.flowPanel.Controls["txtLabel1"];
     MessageBox.Show(txt.ToString());     
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find the layoutUI controls within flowPanel.Controls. Maybe for easier identification, you could set layoutUI.Tag or layoutUI.Name to some distict value.

Comment: Why are you creating a `layoutUI` for each TextBox? Shouldn't be a single one to host the TextBoxes or at least a group of them? If so, create and add the `layoutUI` outside the loop.  Also, you can do `this.Controls.Find("ControlName", true);` to find a control.

Comment: each loop is meant to display result from database

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by changing the following code.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      TextBox txt = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtLabel1", true)[0];
      MessageBox.Show(txt.Text.ToString());
 }
```